# when building a jar, where does Gradle pick the org.gradle.jvm.version from?

Tags: java, gradle

I just upgraded the JDK of an internal library to JDK 17, and I am a bit confused, because it seems I am getting something different between what I build on my machine, and what the CI pipeline builds, while both are supposed to use JDK 17.

in the library, which is a multi-module (it actually builds 2 jars) I've defined this in the top `gradle.build` file :

```
allprojects {
  java {
    toolchain {
      languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
  }
}
```

I am using `'net.researchgate.release' version '3.0.0'` plugin to release.

When I build it locally, here's my Gradle config :

```
gradlew -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.1 (Amazon.com Inc. 17.0.1+12-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

So I am using Java 17...

then I build my library locally with `gradlew clean build publishToMavenLocal` , it generates a jar, and a module file that contains this :

```
   ...
   "createdBy": {
    "gradle": {
      "version": "7.4.2"
    }
  },
  "variants": [
    {
      "name": "apiElements",
      "attributes": {
        "org.gradle.category": "library",
        "org.gradle.dependency.bundling": "external",
        "org.gradle.jvm.version": 11,
        "org.gradle.libraryelements": "jar",
        "org.gradle.usage": "java-api"
    ....
```

the important part here is

```
 "org.gradle.jvm.version": 11
```

Now, when I build the exact same code, but on Jenkins (which also uses JDK 17), using

```
gradlew clean build sonarqube
```

followed by :

```
gradlew release --stacktrace -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true
```

it publishes to Nexus a module file that is similar,  but I notice that it has

```
"org.gradle.jvm.version": 17
```

The problem I have now is that my JDK 11 applications can't use the library built by Jenkins : I get :

```
Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
```

But it works if I use the version built locally, which has no difference apart from the version of the lib itself.

When I change the java tool chain to `17` locally, then the module file says `17`, so it seems to really be that property that controls the value in the module file.

any idea of what could explain this difference of behavior when I run it in Jenkins ? is there a gradle flag to set to get more details on how it's built ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand "why", but I found something simple that works : instead of having the java toolchain in the `allprojects` block, I have it in `subprojects` :

```
subprojects {
  java {
    toolchain {
      languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
  }
}
```

And now both Jenkins and a local build produce the same lib which is JDK 11 compatible.

Hope this helps others, even if I am not able to understand why. Feel free to add a response that explains it.